# Toggle fullscreen mode doesn't work in 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, unity, shortcut-keys, window, fullscreen

According to 'System Settings → Keyboard → Shortcuts → Windows → Toggle fullscreen Mode' I can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> to toggle fullscreen mode of a window. In previous versions of Ubuntu this worked just fine, is this a known bug in Unity?

Comment: Does it do anything for you? For me it maximizes windows (terminal and Chromium).

Comment: Yes it maximizes windows, in that respect it behaves identical to 'System Settings → Keyboard → Shortcuts → Windows → Maximize window'. But it doesn't make windows fullscreen like in older Ubuntu versions (and neither does it toggle).

Comment: I would report this as a bug. One thing you can try are the [steps here.](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1497976&page=2) Basically install `compiz-fusion-plugins-extra` and look for Extra WM Actions under Window Management in CCSM. But I did this and it doesn't seemt to have helped. Perhaps you'll have better luck. Otherwise, see [how do I report a bug.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)